# How can I retrieve a friends friend list from twitter using Asp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I am developing a twitter-like application and I want to retrieve friends friend list using my asp.net web application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [customized library](http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/twitter-c-library/) developed which includes most of twitter API